# join List of dates

Tags: c#

I have a list of datetime object, I want to get a comma separated string from that list with format like `DD/MM/YYYY`, `DD/MM/YYYY`, `DD/MM/YYYY`

```
List<DateTime> dates ...
```

c# snipper for that???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string.Join(",", dates.Select(d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq alternative:

```
String.Join(",", from d in dates select String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", d))
```